# How does this prime function actually work?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Taken from Haskell's home page https://www.haskell.org/

```
primes = filterPrime [2..] 
  where filterPrime (p:xs) = 
          p : filterPrime [x | x <- xs, x `mod` p /= 0]
```

After several minutes looking at this function, I realized I don't really understand what this function is actually doing, I would like to know what is happening.

But first, this is what I believe is happening:

Because of lazy evaluation, only one member from the list comprehension is taken in each iteration... like so:

1st iteration

```
2 : filterPrime [x | x <- [3..], x `mod` p /= 0]
```

2nd iteration

```
2 : 3 : filterPrime [x | x <- [4..], x `mod` p /= 0]
```

3rd iteration

```
??? :(
```

Comment: I believe it's generating a list of prime numbers by seeing if the number in the list comprehension is divisible by the currently found prime numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

well the first one is directly form the pattern match `p:xs` from `[2..]` - so it's `p = 2` and `xs` some thunk

The next needs to evaluate the `xs` and so it needs to evaluate

```
[ x | x <- [3..], x `mod` 2 /= 0 ]
```

which will start with `x = 3` (that is ok with the filter) - so you now have `p:xs` (remember the recursive definition with `filterPrime`) with `p=3` too but this time the `xs` already are filtered for `` `mod` 2 /= 0 `` and will now be filtered for `3` too - this will go on for each found prime - each time you will only look at a remainder of numbers that are not multiples of all the found primes so far.

You see it's a bit like the [sieve of eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) and I guess it's called that too (but there are [some objections](https://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf) to it)

Comment: thanks I think I got it, uhmm ... so basically the function applies a filter to a list already filtered

Comment: Very nice blog post from @Carsten on F# interfaces (prime number 23) for F# advent calendar. http://gettingsharper.de/ . It shows how to simulate rank-2 types in F# with interfaces and object expressions. Of course the syntax is not as clean and fun as Haskell's... but it's OK.

Comment: @FZed :D ... I love to get a bit nerdy - there where so much *good* / **real** articles I **had** to do it - but thank you - glad you liked it